# How many ways to combine two sets so that order of each set is preserved.

Tags: combinatorics

If we have sets $\lbrace1,2,...k\rbrace$  and $\lbrace  k+1,..., n\rbrace$, in how many ways can these sets be combined so that the original two sets respect the original order and 1 is always in front?

For example if k=3, n=5,
12345,

12453,

14523,

12435,

14235,

14253.

There are 3*2 of them.

I don't think the answer is $k*(n-k)$ in general since it doesn't hold when n=4, k=2.

Comment: You have $n-1$ slots, and you must choose $k-1$ of them to place the numbers $2,\ldots, k$.  The numbers $k+1,\ldots,n$ must fall into place after that.  This gives the answer as $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

Comment: I can choose up to $k-1$ of them. But my calculation won't take into account the fact that the order of the objects I place in the slots must respect the original order.

Comment: @Jared is correct: the fact that the numbers must respect the original order means that once you know which slots are to be used, the ordering is completely determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jared and Brian have noted in the comments, all you have to determine is which of the $n - 1$ places (places not including the first $1$) are allocated to the set $\{2,\cdots,k\}$ and which are allocated to $\{k+1,k+2,\cdots ,n\}$.  From there, the order is completely determined since the two subsequences have determined order.  There are $n - 1$ slots and $k - 1$ slots to choose for the first set, so this gives ${{n - 1} \choose {k - 1}}$ possibilities.

A fun side problem is to determine all pairs $(n,k)$ such that ${{n - 1} \choose {k - 1}} = k(n - k)$ as you conjectured.

Answer (score 0):

You have $k$ slots (including the one at the end)  in the first set to put the $n-k$ numbers in where each slot can hold as many numbers as you like.  This is a [weak composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29) of $n-k$ into $k$ parts.  There are ${ n-1 \choose k-1}$ of them